# Next.js and Supabase: Method expects to have requestAsyncStorage

Tags: next.js, supabase

#### The issue:

In prod, Next.js throws that error message: `Invariant: Method expects to have requestAsyncStorage, none available`. This error message occurs only server components and also in prod (Deploy on Cloudflare). No issue in local.

##### Solution is the below.

---

**When it throws the error:**

When it was fetching data from Supabase database in the server components in prod, not local.

**Dependencies:**

```json
"@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs": "^0.7.3",
"@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.31.0",
"next": "13.4.12",
```

**Dashboard component:**

```js
import { createServerSupabaseClient, getSession } from "@/components/supabase/supabase-server";

export default async function Dashboard() {
    const supabase = createServerSupabaseClient() // this line works well.
    const serverSession = await getSession() // this line works well.
    const userInfo = serverSession?.user

    const pending = await supabase
        .from('table')
        .select('*', { count: 'exact', head: true })
        .eq('username', userInfo.user_metadata.username)
        .eq('status', 0)

    // Here's the error:
    console.log("ERROR [PENDING] DETAILS: ", JSON.stringify(pending, null, 2))
}
```

**supabase-server.js:**

```js
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { cache } from 'react';
import { createServerComponentClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';

export const createServerSupabaseClient = cache(() =>
    createServerComponentClient({ cookies })
)

export async function getSession() {
    const supabase = createServerSupabaseClient()
    try {
        const {
            data: { session }
        } = await supabase.auth.getSession()
        return session
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error)
        return null
    }
}
```

**middleware.js:**

```js
import { createMiddlewareClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export async function middleware(req) {
    const res = NextResponse.next()
    const supabase = createMiddlewareClient({ req, res })
    await supabase.auth.getSession()
    return res
}
```

##### Additional:

I guess the problem comes from the `next/headers` package. But why is it working in local? Everything is perfect in the client components, also in local. I don't want to do prop drilling.

A comment about this issue from GitHub: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/52176

- Used `server-only` package
- Removed the `cache()` from `react`
- Run `createServerComponentClient` directly in the Dashboard component, not imported

---

#### The solution:

**Typescript:**

```js
'use server'
import { createServerActionClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'
import { cookies } from 'next/headers'
import { Database } from '@/lib/db_types'

const cookieStore = cookies()
const supabase = createServerActionClient<Database>({
  cookies: () => cookieStore
})
```

**JavaScript `supabase-server.js`:**

```js
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import { cache } from 'react';
import { createServerComponentClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs';

export const createServerSupabaseClient = cache(() => {
    const cookieStore = cookies()
    return createServerComponentClient({ cookies: () => cookieStore })
})

export async function getSession() {
    const supabase = createServerSupabaseClient()
    try {
        const {
            data: { session }
        } = await supabase.auth.getSession()
        return session
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error)
        return null
    }
}
```

1. [More information about the solution](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45371#issuecomment-1655408690)
2. [More information](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49373#issuecomment-1655450565)

Comment: When i run this code, i get (the typescript version) the following error `Only async functions are allowed to be exported in a "use server" file.`

Comment: @Wiezalditzijn please, check your function if it is async. The exported functions in a server component must be async. You may try this method: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/45371#issuecomment-1665413039